# Master Password with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, mongoid

I am following [this link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Configure-a-master-password) to configure a master password with Devise.

Everything works fine in my developement and I am able to login to every user with the master User's password. But in production(I have used Heroku for deployment) the build process breaks down. I have used Compose to host my database with SSL support.

The error is:

```
MONGODB | SSL handshake failed. MongoDB may not be configured with SSL support.
```

I debugged the code and found out the potential culprit:

```
DEFAULT_MASTER_USER = self.find_by(email: DEFAULT_MASTER_USER_EMAIL)
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: DEFAULT_MASTER_USER_EMAIL - have u set this? check the config file

Comment: I have put DEFAULT_MASTER_USER_EMAIL in the User model iteself in the User.rb
Do I need to put it in a config file? Which config file would it be?

Comment: in that case you don't need to put it in there.

Answer (score 0):

This error has nothing to do with devise by the looks of it. Check your mongo url in the config.

Comment: Yes. It has nothing to do with Devise. The problem is rails is not able to access the database with ssl support WHILE DEPLOYMENT. But later it works perfectly.